# call the function in select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have the select box with two option I need to trigger the function in onchange as well as need to call the function for selected option.eg.If I choose the option1 as default it 'll trigger the function but If I choose the same option 1 again it hapends nothing.I want to call the function even I chosen option1 again.

```js
function hello() {
    alert('hello');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div >
  <select onchange="hello()">
    <option  onclick="hello() value="1">Week 1</option>
    <option  value="2">Week 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing a quote between `onclick` and `value`

Comment: onchange will trigger when any value change, I think you can use onclick or onblur events for that

Comment: Why use DOM0-style `onxyz` attributes when you're using jQuery?

Comment: you should avoid using inline event handlers in dom and rather use jquery or javascript to attach onchange event handlers. should you take some action or not depending on the selected option can always be handled in the onchange event handler method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind `mouseup` event handler for the `select` element.

> The mouseup event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer is over
>   the element, and the mouse button is released.

```js
$("select").mouseup(function() {
    var open = $(this).data("isopen");
    if(open) {
        alert('hello');
    }
    $(this).data("isopen", !open);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div >
  <select>
    <option value="1">Week 1</option>
    <option  value="2">Week 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing a quote between `onclick` and `value` - @Ahs N

Comment: Why in heaven's name would you need `mouseup` for this?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, he want to call the function for select change for two times consecutive.With `change` event handler that's not possible. Try to click the already selected option.

Comment: `click` would just be more normal, is all.

Answer (score 3):

It is bad practice to use `onclick` and `onchange`.  I'd recommend using the following to detect value change. Additionally, your code, as written, won't trigger the second `hello()` when you click on `Week 1`.

```js
$("#select").change(function () {
  if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    console.log("you pressed one");
  }
  console.log("you changed the value");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div >
  <select id="select">
    <option value="1">Week 1</option>
    <option value="2">Week 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (details below):

```js
function hello() {
    alert('hello');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select onclick="hello()">
    <option value="1">Week 1</option>
    <option value="2">Week 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7od4Lwro/)

Instead of `onchange` `onclick` is used here, so that function calls on every click irrespective of whether the selection is changed or not.

But its a bad practice to use `onclick` as it add some overheads.

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know, I have tried it, but that is not working. That's why I provide jsfiddle link.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz: Stack Snippets work just fine. See the one I just posted to your answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have used them too, but at that moment it is not responding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <select onmouseup="hello(this)">
    <option value="1">Week 1</option>
    <option value="2">Week 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hello(e){
        var open = $(e).data("isopen");
        if(open)
            alert('hello' + $(e).val());

        $(e).data("isopen", !open);
    }
</script>
```